# Revmob unity plugin video always in landscape mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, revmob, revmobads

After integrating Revmob unity plugin, I have created media id in their admin portal for Android and iOS apps. Then configured media id in unity and everything is setup.

Took build for Android and while running, I am always getting Video ad in landsape mode.

I set orientation to Portrait in activity but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RevMob's video ad orientation does not depend on the app orientation, it depends on the campaigns' orientation.

Comment: When the advertiser creates a video campaign, it is possible to set the orientation under the Creatives tab, and then selecting Video.